# MapView and ListView switch on Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, dictionary

Folks,

What is the best way to implement an activity that has a map Fragment and also a ListView and I can switch the view on a button's click. Should I use a ViewPager? the data I would be using would be accesible on a rest webservice as json and storing that json as the object and populate the list with the data and also populate the map fragment with this data.

thanks,

Comment: instead use two fragments separately for map and list and load them accordingly

Comment: @HRaval would I use a bundle to pass the data between fragments?

Comment: yes you can set bundle using setArgument() method of fragment